# C++ thread safe queue implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, queue

I'm using this class for producer-consumer setup in C++:

```
#pragma once

#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>

template <typename T> class SafeQueue
{
public:
    SafeQueue() :
    _shutdown(false)
    {

    }

    void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mutex);
        bool was_empty = _queue.empty();
        _queue.push(std::move(item));
        lock.unlock();

        if (was_empty)
            _condition_variable.notify_one();
    }

    bool Dequeue(T& item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mutex);

        while (!_shutdown && _queue.empty())
            _condition_variable.wait(lock);

        if(!_shutdown)
        {
            item = std::move(_queue.front());
            _queue.pop();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool IsEmpty()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mutex);
        return _queue.empty();
    }

    void Shutdown()
    {
        _shutdown = true;
        _condition_variable.notify_all();
    }

private:
    std::mutex _queue_mutex;
    std::condition_variable _condition_variable;
    std::queue<T> _queue;
    std::atomic<bool> _shutdown;
};
```

Most of it looks fine to me, but the `Shutdown` function looks like it might have some problems. If there are problems, what is the best way to 'unblock' a thread waiting on `Dequeue` when I want to stop it?

Comment: I would reverse the logic in Dequeue to `if (_shutdown) return false;` and add the return after it, as it is the longer command sequence

Answer (score 2):

Your concerns are correct. The `std::notify_one` [description](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) says that

> Even if the shared variable is atomic, it must be modified under the mutex in order to correctly publish the modification to the waiting thread.

---

Code wise, `return true`/`return false` usually indicate a room for improvement. What you are actually returning is a state of `_shutdown`. Do it explicitly:

```
        if (!shutdown) {
            dequeue item;
        }
        return !_shutdown;
```

You may also notice that `shutdown` is always tested with negation. It indicates that the semantics is reversed. I recommend to replace `shutdown` with something like `keep_running`.

Comment: Thumbs up for this detail: "You may also notice that shutdown is always tested with negation. It indicates that the semantics is reversed. I recommend to replace shutdown with something like keep_running."  This is a general thing applicable various places. I will keep this one in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

You should provide an overload of Enqueue that takes an rvalue reference:

```
void Enqueue(T&& item)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mutex);
    bool was_empty = _queue.empty();
    _queue.push(std::move(item));
    lock.unlock();

    if (was_empty)
        _condition_variable.notify_one();
}
```

The current code can call the move constructor twice for any given:

```
queue.Enqeueu(std::move(item));
```

I would also suggesting replacing or supplementing your `Deque` method with one that can take advantage of NRVO

```
T Dequeue()
{   
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mutex);

    while (!_shutdown && _queue.empty())
        _condition_variable.wait(lock);

    if(_shutdown){
        throw std::runtime_error("shutdown"); //replace with your own exception
    }   

    T item = std::move(_queue.front());
    _queue.pop();
    return item;
}
```

Since the user of the class is in control of both `Shutdown()` and `Dequeue()` it does seem that calling dequeue on a queueu that is shutting down is an exceptional condition.